# IdentityServer4 ResourceStore - IdentityResource vs ApiResource

Tags: identityserver4

I'm trying to setup IdentityServer4 to work with my own (mongodb) database, instead of the in-memory examples shown in the documentation.

To do so I have configured the following services:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IClientStore, ClientStore>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceStore, ResourceStore>();
```

In my databases I've created 4 collections: "ApiResources", "IdentityResources" and "Clients".

In the ApiResources I've defined what should be the API I'm protecting:

```
{ 
    "Name" : "MyAPI", 
    "DisplayName" : "Test API Resource"
}
```

In IdentityResources I've defined what should be my identities:

```
{ 
    "Name" : "MyIdentity", 
    "DisplayName" : "Test Identity Resource"
}
```

And I have defined the following client:

```
{ 
    "ClientId" : "client", 
    "Enabled" : true, 
    "ClientSecrets" : [
        {
            "Description" : null, 
            "Value" : "K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=", 
            "Expiration" : null, 
            "Type" : "SharedSecret"
        }
    ], 
    "ClientName" : null, 
    "ClientUri" : null, 
    "LogoUri" : null, 
    "RequireConsent" : true, 
    "AllowRememberConsent" : true, 
    "AllowedGrantTypes" : [
        "client_credentials"
    ], 
    "AllowedScopes" : [
        "MyAPI"
    ], 
    "Claims" : [

    ], 
    "AllowedCorsOrigins" : [

    ]
}
```

My database representation is similar to what is represented in the example in the documentation.

In my `IResourceStore` implementation, for `FindIdentityResourcesByScopeAsync` I look for the scopes names in my `IdentityResources` collection (as the name of the method implies) and in my `FindApiResourcesByScopeAsync` I look for the scopes in my `ApiResources` collection as the name implies.

When I try to authenticate the client against the server I'm getting `Requested scope not allowed: MyAPI`.

But if I change my code in `FindIdentityResourcesByScopeAsync` to the the `ApiResources` then it works.

Is this a bug? or do I not get exactly what's the difference between IdentityResources and ApiResources? When should each be used? If in `FindIdentityResourcesByScopeAsync` I should take my API resource, what should I take in `FindApiResourcesByScopeAsync`?

Comment: I hope that the Base64 secret is a fake/testing one.

Comment: @Falk no worries - it is. It's the default tutorial hash.

Answer (score 3):

So I finally figured out what the problem was. Although returning the API Resource when asked `FindIdentityResourcesByScopeAsync` - This is obviously not the way to go.

I finally noticed that the problem was actually in the `ApiResource` object returned by `FindApiResourcesByScopeAsync`. While it was returning an `ApiResource` with the name of the API I want to grant access to, that object did not contain any values for the `Scopes`, which should also contain a record of `MyAPI`.

The thing I do not understand here is what is this `Scopes` object. And why it should contain the `MyAPI` definition again (like the parent object). What other `Scopes` should/can I add here and what are their meaning?

Comment: A `Scope` is used when the client should not have access to the whole API (the 'Resource'), but only a part of it. The `ApiResource` is used to grant access to the whole API.

Comment: ie. there might be an `new ApiResource("MyApi", "My API")`, as well as `new Scope("MyApi.ReadWrite", "Read-write access to my API")` and `new Scope("MyApi.ReadOnly", "Read-only access to my API")`.